# Multi-cursor selection (match case, match whole word) in Visual Studio Code with a single shortcut keypress?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I couldn't find, is there a way to perform **multi-cursor selection** (**match case**, **match whole word**) in Visual Studio Code with a single shortcut key press?

here is some sample code, I want to do **multi-cursor selection** of all appearances of the word **news**. Is such action supported?

*I know there is a **Ctrl+D** option, but it requires many keypress jumping from one to another, also it is not case sensitive.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Mac-OS press:

`ALT + CMD + C` then `SHIFT + CMD + L`